# How Hibernate SessionFactory autowired using LocalSessionFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

Autowiring is happening perfectly and everything works fine. 
But i need to know how session factory is injected in `HibernateTransactionManager` using `LocalSessionFactoryBean` though 
no relation between `LocalSessionFactoryBean`  class and `SessionFactory` interface.

PFB the code i used in my project

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="localSessionFactoryBean" />
    </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="localSessionFactoryBean"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

In the above code, I am injecting `LocalSessionFactoryBean` for `sessionFactory` in `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Please, explain how `sessionFactory` is initialized in `HibernateTransactionManager` from `LocalSessionFactoryBean` using annotation driven in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocalSessionFactoryBean` implements `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`. So when Spring sets `sessionFactory` to the `HibernateTransactionManager` it calls `getObject()` methods of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and gets `SessionFactory`.

```
public class LocalSessionFactoryBean extends HibernateExceptionTranslator
        implements FactoryBean<SessionFactory> {

    public SessionFactory getObject() {
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

[What's a FactoryBean?](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean)